# Argument of \@tempa has an extra }. Runaway argument?

Tags: subfloats

I have a latex source file in which authors are trying to include figures side by side without using subfigure.
I know it is related to subfigure but I am unable to sort it out.
In case of giving citation in caption, similar problem arises for which `\protect` command is useful (seperate thread for this available). Following is a part of file.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{colt2019_arxiv}
\usepackage{wrapfig,caption}
\usepackage[colorinlistoftodos,textwidth=1in]{todonotes}
\captionsetup{%
    font=small,
    labelfont=bf,
    singlelinecheck=false,
    tableposition=top
}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{times}
\newcommand{\algo}{XYZ\xspace}
\newcommand{\nocontentsline}[3]{}
\newcommand{\tocless}[2]{\bgroup\let\addcontentsline=\nocontentsline#1{#2}\egroup}
\newcommand{\AD}{\algo\xspace}
\title[help in Tex required ]{The code\\is not running}
\begin{document}
    \maketitle
    \vspace{-20pt}
    \begin{abstract}
        We study the problem of 
    \end{abstract}
    \begin{keywords}%
        regression
    \end{keywords}
    \tocless\input{intro1.tex}
    \clearpage
    \bibliography{local}
    \clearpage
    \appendix
    \onecolumn
    \setcounter{tocdepth}{2}
    \tableofcontents
    \newpage
\end{document}
```

The file intro1.tex contains following :

```
\section{Introduction}
\label{sec:intro}
We study least squares 
\citep{abcxyz}. \citet{abcxyz} \algo-FC (see Figure~\ref{fig:main}).
\begin{figure}[t]
    \centering
    \includegraphics[scale=0.21]{plots/e1.eps}
    \includegraphics[scale=0.21]{plots/e2.eps}
    \includegraphics[scale=0.21]{plots/e3.eps}\vspace*{-3pt}
    \caption{\small{\protect\algo is able to do xyz.}}\vspace{-3ex}
    \label{fig:main}
\end{figure}
```

Comment: `\protect\algo`

Comment: The problem persists even after using  `\protect\algo`

Comment: Please, make a complete *short* example, from `\documentclass` to `\end{document}`, that shows the issue

Comment: @egreg Sir, I have edited the question.

Comment: Unrelated `\small` does not take any arguments and does nothing due to your captions setting above.

Comment: Also not that this example is NOT complete, others cannot just copy it an try it. Make a single document that others can copy and test without having to add or edit anything.

Comment: @daleif I have edited so that one can give it a try.

Comment: You can just as well add the intro1 stuff into the example, it does not need to be an external file. Additionally we do not have your images, you might want to use `\rule{3cm}{3cm}` instead, and lastly, that document class is not a known class. It is relevant (can `article` be used instead? if not provide a link to the class).

Comment: I am providing link to the actual document. This is from arxiv. Unzipping will give all the required files. 
https://arxiv.org/e-print/1903.08192

Comment: When I tried to make document class as article, the figures did come. I am not understanding whether it is a problem of letex class or including figures in this fashion. @daleif

Comment: As I see it you are using a 2017 version of jmlr.cls which does not work with `graphicx` (I think) unless you are also using a latex installation that is from 2018 or older. It fails on TeXLive 2019. I've I remove (rename) the copies of `jmlr.cls` and `jmlrutils.sty` that are in the arxiv sources and thus it uses the one from my current LaTeX, the code works just fine. But there is a caveat here: arXiv uses quite old latex, so you are in a bit of a pickle here if arxiv does not provide `jmlr.cls` via their own latex installation.

Comment: \includegraphics[scale=0.21]{plots/e3.eps}\vspace*{-3pt} Please see \includegraphics[scale=0.21]{plots/e3.eps}\vspace{-3pt} I removed *, which I feel that it has no meaning.

Comment: I do not see how this answers to the question. Do you meant to edit the original post?

Comment: @ClaudioFiandrino The answer given to this problem by Egreg worked out. I am still not understanding root cause of the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can “fix” the issue by adding

```
\makeatletter
\let\Ginclude@graphics\@org@Ginclude@graphics
\makeatother
```

just after the `\documentclass` line, so removing the wrong checks `jmlr.cls` does when processing `\includegraphics`.

Comment: Thanks. This worked. If possible can you explain what was going wrong.

Comment: @ketanbapat The version of `jmlr.cls` shipped along with the paper does a redefinition of `\Ginclude@graphics` that clashes with the most recent LaTeX kernel and `graphicx` package.